# regular expression in javascript checking for "asdasd<something>asdsada"

Tags: javascript, regex

how would I check for string
`<something>` in `var string = "some chars <something> somechars"`

Comment: just search for /\ and replace it with /{/{anything/}/}

Comment: i wanted to post something else

Comment: I mean how to check for <something> in "asdas <something> asdasd"

Comment: @Manish Use Markdown formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Man your question is very dynamic / transient. It has super fast edits.

Comment: This is the question I wnated to ask. thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`String.match()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp):

```
var res = string.match(/<something>/g); // ["<something>"]
```

If there is no match, the value of `res` will be `null`. See example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2G3Y/).